# Stripe: How to provide access during grace period

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, stripe-payments

I have a couple of monthly plans where user can cancel at any moment. Whats the recommended way to handle a `grace period` where a user still gets access to the application. For example. If the users signup on 1st July and cancels on 15th July, I would like the provide the user access till 30th July.

i am storing the following columns, `current_period_start`, `current_period_end`, `canceled_at` & `ended_at`.

should grace period check be something like

```
def grace_period?
   return status == 'canceled' && Time.zone.now < current_period_end
end
```

any clarification on this would be really helpful. thanks.

Comment: If you are using Stripe this is an option when you make the cancellation.  There should be a `cancel_at_period_end` property you can set

Comment: yes you should use `cancel_at_period_end` so that the customer's trial cancels at the end of the current period.

Answer (score 1):

You should not "cancel" subscription.
Just update with parameter "cancel_at_period_end: true"